# locationProvider not working for angular

Tags: angularjs

While working on a course from [Pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angularjs-forms-bootstrap-mvc5/table-of-contents) ,  I am having a problem.

```js
angularFormsApp.config(
    ["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     $routeProvider
    .when("/home", {
        templateUrl: "app/Home.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
    })
    .when("/newEmployee", {
        templateUrl: "app/Employee/employeeTemplate.html",
        controller: "employeeController"
    })
    .when("/updateEmployee/:id", {
            templateUrl: "app/Employee/employeeTemplate.html",
            controller: "employeeController"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/home"
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}]);
```

I had to add 'requireBase' after looking into a forum as it was giving error without using this. Now if run my code, I can't go to Update Employee page directly. When I clicked Update Employee, nothing happened, i pressed cancel and then 'Add Employee' but the 'Update Employee' became visible instead of 'Add'. When I clicked submit, it gave me 'Not Found' server side error without entering debugging code.

I commented the  code

```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
```

to see the urls being passed and then it worked. Can you please help me on this as practically we have to use this code to hide the urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found an answer. The shortcut to this method is:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This will be equal to

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: true,
    rewriteLinks: true
});
```

What I was doing wrong was when I used the shortcut, my f12 tools in the browser were giving the following error:
"locationProvider require a base href tag"
I confused this with the requireBase parameter in the above statement and nothing worked for me.
I added the following:

```
 <base href="/" />
```

in the head section of my Index.cshtml page and it worked.